# saveToGallery SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting bucket_id

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I cannot save chart. I get false retured value from `saveToGallery`, and what I see in `logs` is:

> SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting bucket_id=-2075821635 date_modified=1544882049 is_hw_burst=0 datetaken=1     544882049000 bucket_display_name=DCIM parent=8 format=14337 storage_id=65537 media_type=1 mime_type=image/jpeg title=chart.jpg d     escription=MPAndroidChart-Library Save _data=/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/chart.jpg _size=33015 date_added=1544882049 _display_name=     chart.jpg orientation=0.

I have all permissions in Manifest and also `runtime` permission granted.
What is the root cause?

This is method I use for verification at `runtime`

```
public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
        // Check if we have write permission
        int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }
}
```

And this is used to save chart:

```
case R.id.fab_save:
            boolean saved = lineChart.saveToGallery(file_name,100);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File saved "+saved, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with uniqueness of `file_name`. For example it can be:

```
`Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
                String ts = tsLong.toString();
            boolean saved = lineChart.saveToGallery(file_name+ts,100);`
```